# Effect of 'Prime conspiracy' on the fact that prime numbers are the generators of integers

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, algebraic-number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-gaps

In [Unexpected biases in the distribution of consecutive primes](http://arxiv.org/abs/1603.03720), the authors have discovered that  [prime numbers have decided preferences about the final digits of the primes that immediately follow them](http://www.wired.com/2016/03/mathematicians-discovered-prime-conspiracy/). This is being called as 'Prime conspiracy'.

We have known the prime numbers as [the generators of integers, rationals, etc](http://my.ilstu.edu/~lmiones/ISUP/ProjDesc12_v3.pdf). Does this new discovery affect this fact in any way? To be clearer, does this new discovery give us any new information about other branches of number theory?

Comment: The endding digits of the natural numbers are equally distributed, so the preferences obviously vanish after the primes have been multplied together.